# Update multiple fields in a table

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to update multiple fields value in `transsit` column in the table `tracking_details`.

I have a table named `tracking_details` and which consist of two columns `id` and `transsit`

Example `tracking_details` table:-

```
id  |   transsit
------------------
1   |   rec
2   |   rec
3   |   sen
4   |
5   |   rec
```

Here, I would like to change `rec` to `received` where `id` equal `1,2 and 5`

And what I have done so far is:

```
UPDATE tracking_details
SET transsit = 'received'
WHERE id = (select id from tracking_details where transsit='rec');
```

Then I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

********** Error **********

ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE tracking_details
SET transsit = 'received'
WHERE id IN (select id from tracking_details where transsit='rec');
```

For multiple row update use `IN` instead of `=` because `=` will always have only one row or simply you can use join.

```
UPDATE tracking_details a
JOIN tracking_details b
  ON a.id=b.id
SET a.transsit = 'received'
Where b.transsit='rec';
```

Furthurmore looking at query you do it using single query

```
UPDATE tracking_details 
SET transsit = 'received'
WHERE transsit='rec';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do an `UPDATE` with a `WHERE` clause:

```
 UPDATE tracking_details
        SET transsit = 'received'
        WHERE transsit = 'rec';
```